# What happens when Closing as offtopic>>Software development?

Tags: discussion, support, moderation

Several times I have voted to close questions as Off-Topic>>Question is about Software Development, because I think that it is better suited for Stack Overflow.

[image]

These questions usually get closed. I have a few questions about this:

- What is the Standard Operating Procedure for the OP in this kinds of questions? Should (s)he ask the question again on the appropriate site? Or will this question be Migrated there?
- Do I need to flag this question for Moderator Attention and ask that it be migrated?

Comment: +1 - I've wondered this too

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to flag and ask for the Q to be migrated, the reason for close already covers that.

The first point has room for interpretation. Before migrating a moderator needs to exercise judgement on whether the destination site will indeed welcome the question, and that requires familiarity with the destination. Even when it is clear the Q could and should be migrated it is often better for the OP to rephrase anyway.

That aside, a quick review of the last 5 posts migrated to S.O. reveal they were all flagged as *"off-topic >> belong elsewhere"* first.

I tried to determine if there were any questions closed as belonging on S.O. and not migrated, but failed to find any ([closed:yes duplicate:no migrated:no is:question developer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/search?q=closed%3Ayes+duplicate%3Ano+migrated%3Ano+is%3Aquestion+developer)). Some more time spent developing better search-fu might reveal different results.

So yes, flagging to close as belongs elsewhere is sufficient.

(I personally have not migrated many questions, those Mods who have may have an alternate perspective.)

Comment: Thank you Matt, for your perspective.